# Where to run command for pgloader

Tags: pgloader

I have installed the pgloader using Window Subsystem Linux.

I couldn't figure out where to run the pgloader commands, for example, loading CSV data: https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/csv.html

```
LOAD CSV
   FROM 'GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv' WITH ENCODING iso-646-us
        HAVING FIELDS
        (
           startIpNum, endIpNum, locId
        )
   INTO postgresql://user@localhost:54393/dbname
        TARGET TABLE geolite.blocks
        TARGET COLUMNS
        (
           iprange ip4r using (ip-range startIpNum endIpNum),
           locId
        )
   WITH truncate,
        skip header = 2,
        fields optionally enclosed by '"',
        fields escaped by backslash-quote,
        fields terminated by '\t'

    SET work_mem to '32 MB', maintenance_work_mem to '64 MB';
```

Whenever I run the commands in the cmd, it won't recognize the syntax:

> -bash: LOAD: command not found

Comment: "Whenever I run the commands" can you provide the commands that you're running (the exact syntax you're using)

Comment: forgot to add the doc. Added the doc @Samathingamajig

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to put your commands in a .lisp file then execute the following command :

```
pgloader yourfile.lisp
```

Of course ensure pgloader is installed or that you use the binary you compiled.